# save a sheet from spreadsheet as pdf in same google drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

I am trying to make a code that gets all files from a google drive folder, then converts all files to excel and save in same folder and also make pdf files from second sheet 'V2' of each spreadsheet and save in same folder.

I am successful in creating excel folder but pdf part is not working. I have copied code from many different sources.

```
function Generator(){
  //Factors to change every month
  var folderID = '14Bz9LLAiv2BgsT4bowxUtMfG2AsTxk91';
  
  
  // Loop through all the files and save as excel and pdf.
  var reportsFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = reportsFolder.getFiles();
  var TAB_NAME = 'V2' //For pdf
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var bnkFile = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var name = file.getName();
    //Creating Excel files
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + file.getId() + "/export?format=xlsx&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName(name + ".xlsx"); // Modified
    reportsFolder.createFile(blob);
    //Creating PDF files
    var VName =  name.replace("REPORT", "V2");
    var V2Sheet = bnkFile.getSheetByName(TAB_NAME);
    var url2 = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + V2Sheet.getId() + "/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var blob2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2).getBlob().setName(VName + ".pdf"); // Modified
    reportsFolder.createFile(blob2);
    
  }
}
```

Any simple solution for generating PDFs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

You need to specify both the `id` of the **spreadsheet** file but also the `gid` of the **sheet** itself.

**Replace**

```
var url2 = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + V2Sheet.getId() + "/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
```

with

```
var url2 = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ file.getId() + "/export?format=pdf&id="+file.getId()+"&gid="+V2Sheet.getSheetId();
```

---

**Replace**

```
var bnkFile = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

with

```
var bnkFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
```

to get the `spreadsheet` object of the `file`. Your current code gets the active `spreadsheet` which is the spreadsheet that this script is attached to.

Also use the `requestData` object as I define it in my solution.

---

### Solution:

```
function Generator(){
  //Factors to change every month
  var folderID = '14Bz9LLAiv2BgsT4bowxUtMfG2AsTxk91';
  
  // Loop through all the files and save as excel and pdf.
  var reportsFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = reportsFolder.getFiles();
  var TAB_NAME = 'V2' //For pdf
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    
    if(file.getMimeType()=='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'){
    
    var bnkFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    var name = file.getName();
    //Creating Excel files
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + file.getId() + "/export?format=xlsx&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName(name + ".xlsx"); // Modified
    reportsFolder.createFile(blob);
    //Creating PDF files
    var VName =  name.replace("REPORT", "V2");
    var V2Sheet = bnkFile.getSheetByName(TAB_NAME);
    var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
    var url2 = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ file.getId() + "/export?format=pdf&id="+file.getId()+"&gid="+V2Sheet.getSheetId();
    var blob2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2,requestData).getBlob().setName(VName + ".pdf"); // Modified
    var pdfFile = reportsFolder.createFile(blob2);
    var pdfUrl = pdfFile.getUrl(); // <- pdfUrl will give you the url of the pdf file.

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marios, thank you for explaining it right way. I got some things cleared in my mind. However the code is still not working for me as it is giving error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetId' of null " on line "var url2 = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ file.getId() + "/export?format=pdf&id="+file.getId()+"&gid="+V2Sheet.getSheetId();"
I thought it may be due to correct sheet name not entered but it is confirmed that TAB_NAME = V2 is correct. What could be the other reason?

Comment: @Ajmul I think that is hapenning because in the **same** folder you have other types of files like (PDFs or excel files). Please **try** again my **updated** solution. I added an if condition to generate excel files and pdfs only for files of a **spreadsheet** type. Also please make sure that the sheet name is `V2` and not `V2 ` or ` V2` or `V 2` or `v2` etc.

Comment: Awesome, changing the sheet name worked. It was different in some sheets.

Comment: It is working perfectly, I started thinking it was not possible :D I have a small question: Is it possible to save link of file that is created with "reportsFolder.createFile(blob2);" so that I can save that link to a sheet for every file created with an i++